# How to reference window functions and properties

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a custom object which has all the properties and functions of browser "window" object.
Any functions that are mimicking window object functions should just reference to the original window object and execute with original context.

So any methods in new objects should just point to existing window object function with original context

```
NEWOBJECT.FUNCTON_NAME  ->  WINDOW.FUNCTION_NAME
```

How would I do this ?

is it even possible to do ?

I was trying something like this :

```
function OurWindow() {

}

var obj = window;

do Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(key) {

    var ptype = Object.prototype.toString.call(window[key]).slice(8, -1);
    // if function
    if (ptype == 'Function') {

        OurWindow.prototype[key] = window[key].bind(window);

    }

});
while(obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
```

But I am having problems with functions/properties like "Object" which are of function type and have their own children functions, they are not referenced in the new duplicate object.

for example

```
 OurWindow.Object.getOwnPropertyNames  is undefined
```

Comment: "…and execute with original context". Impossible, you can't fake an [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10). Code is either running in a particular context (global, function, eval) or it isn't.

Comment: It would be `.bind(window)`, btw.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: I am trying to insulate global context for different javascript modules, so they can co-exist without conflicts. This is part of a bigger framework I am writing, which is why I am doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want all global methods to be called with *this* set to the global object. So you might do something like the following (noting that this requires ES5 methods that must be polyfilled if feature testing shows they aren't available):

```
(function(globalObject) {
  var globalProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(globalObject);
  globalProps.forEach(function(v) {

    if (typeof globalObject[v] == 'function') {
      globalObject[v] = globalObject[v].bind(globalObject);
    }
  });
}(this));
```

But why do you want to do that? Perhaps you are using strict mode and don't want *this* to be undefined when calling global methods without providing a base reference? But it seems to me that would only make sense for native methods, not built–in methods.